# Show only the information of this date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, foreach

I have 4 dates of 4 people,I want to bring the name of the person who added that date but when I select the day the array is traversed 4 times and in one of them it brings the name.. that is to say the array travels all the people but not only the one I want.
for example on day 17 when I select it 2 alerts come out with error the third with the name of the person and the fourth alert error.. the others are similar

[View picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dfota.jpg)

The code is this,the function of interest is `infoDay`

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selected: "",
      usuarios: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("DatosCli/")
      .on("child_added", (data) => {
        var datos = data.val();
        /*  alert(JSON.stringify(datos));  */
        var usuariosTemp = this.state.usuarios;
        datos.key = data.key;
        //Alert.alert("prueba",""+datos.longitud)
        usuariosTemp.push(datos);
        this.setState({ usuarios: usuariosTemp });
      });
  }

  cargarDatos = async () => {
    var userTemp = new Array();
    var data = await firebase.database().ref("/DatosCli").once("value");

    data.forEach((child) => {
      var user = child.val();
      user.key = child.key;
      userTemp.push(user);
    });
    this.setState({ usuarios: userTemp });
  };



   render() {
    const markedDates = {};
    this.state.usuarios.forEach((usuarioTemp) => {
      markedDates[usuarioTemp.date] = {
        selected: true,
        disableTouchEvent: false,
        selectedColor: "orange",
        selectedTextColor: "red",
      };
    });

    const infoDay = (day) => {
      this.state.usuarios.forEach((usuarioTemp) => {
        if (day.dateString == usuarioTemp.date) {
          alert(usuarioTemp.nombre);
        } else {
          alert("fail");
        }
      });
    };
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CalendarList markedDates={markedDates} onDayPress={infoDay} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you maintain a map ,where date is a key and all the person are added in the array and store it as a value in map It will be something like . {"date":["person1","person2"]} .

Comment: write to console and look at value type and compare (day.dateString == usuarioTemp.date) console.log(day.dateString)  console.log(usuarioTemp.date) 

look at console.log(day) too

Comment: I’ll have to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the else statement you'll only see the correct alerts.

```
const infoDay = (day) => {
      this.state.usuarios.forEach((usuarioTemp) => {
        if (day.dateString == usuarioTemp.date) {
          alert(usuarioTemp.nombre);
        }
      });
    };
```

If you want to travel trough a specific user, you must have to make a dict with the user names

For example:

```
let usuarioTemp = {
    firstUser:{day: 17},
    secondUser:{day: 19}
}
```

And your function could it be:

```
const infoDay = (day, userName) => {
     if(usuarioTemp[userName].date === day){
        alert(userName);
     }
};
```

And finally, I suppose you are getting the data like this:

```
[{nombre:"Name", date:17}, {nombre:"Name2", date:19}]
```

You can use this function:

```
function groupBy(array, key) {
  let arrayReduced = array.reduce(
    (result, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
      (result[k] = rest);
      return result;
    },
    {}
  );
  return arrayReduced;
}
```

and you'll see the data like this:

```
{
"Name": {date: 17},
"Name2": {date: 19}
}
```

Test:

```js
//Data example
let data = [{nombre:"Name", date:17}, {nombre:"Name2", date:19}]

//Function groupBy
function groupBy(array, key) {
  let arrayReduced = array.reduce(
    (result, { [key]: k, ...rest }) => {
      (result[k] = rest);
      return result;
    },
    {}
  );
  return arrayReduced;
}

//Usage
console.log(groupBy(data, "nombre"))
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help